# Multithreading How can I share hash of hash arrays

Tags: perl

I am trying to use threads while assigning an array to a hash and another array to a hash of hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/Perl

use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my %hash :shared;
my %hash1 :shared;

my $a = "abcdef";
my $b = "ghighi";

my $len = length($a)-2;

# Define the number of threads
my $num_of_threads = 2;

# use the initThreads subroutine to create an array of threads.
my @threads = initThreads();

# Loop through the array:
foreach(@threads){
                # Tell each thread to perform our 'doOperation()' subroutine.
        $_ = threads->create(\&doOperation);
}

# This tells the main program to keep running until all threads have finished.
foreach(@threads){
    $_->join();
}

print "\nProgram Done!\nPress Enter to exit";
$a = <>;

####################### SUBROUTINES ############################
sub initThreads{
    my @initThreads;
    for(my $i = 1;$i<=$num_of_threads;$i++){
        push(@initThreads,$i);
    }
    return @initThreads;
}
sub doOperation{
    # Get the thread id. Allows each thread to be identified.
    my $id = threads->tid();
    my $i = 0;

    while($i < 2)
    {

        my $split = substr($a, $i, $len);
        my $split1 = substr($b, $i, $len);

        my $affix = substr($split, 0, $len-1);
        my $postfix = substr($split, 1, $len-1); 
        my $affix1 = substr($split1, 0, $len-1);
        my $postfix1 = substr($split1, 1, $len-1); 

    print "$affix\t$postfix\n";

        lock(%hash);
        #lock(%hash1); 

        $hash{$affix} = threads::shared::shared_clone([$affix1]);
    print "$hash{$affix}\n";
        #$hash1{$affix}{$postfix} = threads::shared::shared_clone([$affix1]); This is where the problem is. How can I assign an array to a hash of hash

        $i++
    }
    print "Thread $id done!\n";
    # Exit the thread
    threads->exit();
}
```

Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Invalid value for shared scalar.

This is part of my code. How can I assign an array to a hash of hash when using threads.e.g.$hash1{$affix}{$postfix} = threads::shared::shared_clone([$affix1]); This is where the problem is. How can I assign an array to a hash of hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$h{x}{y}
```

is short for

```
$h{x}->{y}
```

and dereferences autovivify, so it's effectively

```
( $h{x} //= {} )->{y}
```

Now, you want to a reference to a shared hash, so

```
$hash1{$affix} //= &share({});
$hash1{$affix}{$postfix} = shared_clone([$affix1]);
```

Comment: Sobrique is right though. If you can use a worker module, that would far more ideal.

Comment: Yes, I will consider his approach too. For this approach $hash1{$affix}{$postfix} = shared_clone([$affix1]); only one value is saved for each key. A key can have multiple values. Previously, when I solved this problem without threads I used push @{$hash1{$affix}{$postfix}}, $affix1; or  $hash1{$affix}{$postfix} = [$affix1]; and it saved all the key values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Personally: I wouldn't.

I dislike how cumbersome `threads::shared` makes the process of sharing a hash, so so steer away from it unless it's absolutely necessary.

Given your code, I would suggest is isn't - and you would be better off using `Thread::Queue` to collate results from your threads. It *looks* like you're updating an isolated element, without needing to read it back. So you could:

```
use Thread::Queue;
use threads; 

my $task_q = Thread::Queue -> new(); 
my $result_q = Thread::Queue -> new(); 

sub worker { 
   while ( my $item = $task_q -> dequeue ) { 
       #extract a value to work on
       my $result = "something"; 
       $result_q -> enqueue ( $result ); 
   }
}

for ( 1..$nthreads ) {
    threads -> create ( \&worker );
}

#enqueue one or more items; 
$work_q -> enqueue ( "abcde" ); 

#close the work queue. 
$work_q -> end; 

foreach my $worker ( threads -> list() ) {
   $worker -> join;
}

$results_q -> end;

while ( my $item = $results_q -> dequeue ) {
      #process $item;
}
```

Which'll mean you don't actually need to have a shared hash at all.

Also - avoid using `$a` and `$b` - they are variables with a special meaning in perl - they're used by `sort` and so they don't get namespace checked in the same ways.